# Verifies that the parent of list is a DOM node of type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, html

I need to write a function (p.e. `permuteChildren()`) that:

- Verifies that the parent is a DOM node of type `Element`. If not, it abandons by returning `false`.
- Cleans parent from any direct child that is not of type `Element`.
- Randomly permutes parent's direct child elements.

Once this job accomplished, the function returns `true`.

I need to write it in Pure DOM only (no frameworks) and no HTML text (eg. innerHTML) manipulation.

Here's an example:

```
<ul>
    <li>Apple
        <ul>
            <li>Golden</li>
            <li>Lady</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Pear</li>
    <li>Strawberry</li>
    <li>Lemon</li>
</ul>
```

After the call to `permuteChildren(<the root UL node>)` the structure would become:

```
<ul>
    <li>Strawberry</li>
    <li>Pear</li>
    <li>Lemon</li>
    <li>Apple
    <ul>
        <li>Golden</li>
        <li>Lady</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you want someone to write it for you or learn how to do it ? Because ready code is not the best learning option

Comment: Thanks Jakob, sorry if it's look like that. I never worked with DOM nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go - the code is simple and self-explanatory, but hit me up in the comment if you need further explanations:

```js
const permuteChildren = parent => {
  
  // Verifies that the parent is a DOM node of type Element
  if (!(parent instanceof Element)) return false;
  
  // Cleans parent from any direct child that is not of type Element
  for (let child of parent.children) {
    if (!(child instanceof Element)) {
      child.remove();
    }
  }
  
  // Randomly permutes parent's direct child elements
  let children = [...parent.children];
  Array.from(parent.children).forEach(child => child.remove());
  while (children.length!=0) {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*children.length);
    parent.appendChild(
      children.splice(randomIndex, 1)[0]
    )
  }
  
}

permuteChildren(document.querySelector('ul'));
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Apple
        <ul>
            <li>Golden</li>
            <li>Lady</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Pear</li>
    <li>Strawberry</li>
    <li>Lemon</li>
</ul>
```